# how to prove I install with source APM(apache, php, mysql) not install-package?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, apm

I installed apache, php, mysql in ubuntu server with wget, make, make install.
I finally made it.
but I don't know how to prove or check I installed them with source code.
I checked history command but it was just part of commands not all.
please let me know if you know about it.

Comment: What proof are you expecting beyond the fact that you did those things yourself? Who do you need to prove this to and why? Why does it matter if you built it from source or not?

Comment: I just want to check If is correctly installed with source code and I would like know what is different between source code and install-package.

Comment: If you compiled and installed it yourself, it will not appear as installed in your package management software (ex. apt, or synaptic, or rpm, or ...).

Comment: Distro packages use `/usr` as the prefix, while `autoconf` defaults to `/usr/local`. You can check (e.g. `which mysql`) whether your binaries are in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.